# ElasticSearch - How to get minimum timestamp in each aggregation buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aggregation

I'm having the following document in ElasticSearch:

```
"ip": "192.168.10.12", "@timestamp": "2017-08-10T00:00:00.000Z", "states": "newyork", "user" : "admin"

"ip": "192.168.10.12", "@timestamp": "2017-08-10T01:25:00.000Z", "states": "California", "user" : "guest"
```

I tried to use Elasticsearch terms aggregation by user
This is where I'm at:

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "must":[
           {
              "term":{
                 "user":"admin"
              }
           },
           {
              "range":{
                 "@timestamp":{
                    "gte": "2017-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "lte": "2017-08-10T04:58:00.000Z"
                 }
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  "aggs":{
     "states":{
        "terms":{
           "field":"states",
            "min_doc_count":8
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and from the query ,will return :

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "states": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "New York",
               "doc_count": 200
            },
            {
               "key": "California",
               "doc_count": 10
            },

            {
               "key": "North Dakota",
               "doc_count": 125
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get minimum @timestamp in each bucket ,

but from the return can I get each bucket "minimum" @timestamp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a `min` metric sub-aggregation

```
  "aggs":{
     "states":{
        "terms":{
           "field":"states",
            "min_doc_count":8
        }, 
        "aggs": {
            "min_timestamp": {
               "min": {
                  "field": "@timestamp"
               }
            }   
        }
     }
  }
```